# Adding flags to a batch script

Tags: batch-file, flags

I'm writing a Batch script that will run on a directory. I want to be able to add a flag (such as -r or /r or something like that) that will make the script run the folder tree instead of the single directory. Is it possible to add flag options using batch?

Thanks

Comment: [command line parameters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php).  Did you bother [Googling this](http://goo.gl/e6Kc9)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Bat file optional argument parsing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973824/windows-bat-file-optional-argument-parsing)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Certainly it's possible.  Command line parameters are passed in to your batch file as %1, %2, etc.  (%0 is the name of the batch file.)

```
IF "%1"=="/r" ECHO You passed the /r flag.
```

Use `SHIFT` to drop the first argument and move all the others over by one.  You can use that to get a bit fancier if you want to allow that /r to be anywhere in the command line.  For example:

```
:processargs
SET ARG=%1
IF DEFINED ARG (
    IF "%ARG%"=="/r" ECHO You passed the /r flag.
    SHIFT
    GOTO processargs
)
```

Or use `%*` (which expands to the entire argument list) in a `FOR` loop like this:

```
FOR %%A IN (%*) DO (
    IF "%%A"=="/r" ECHO You passed the /r flag.
)
```

Comment: You can also process arguments as `%*` with a `for` loop.  [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15002975/1683264)

Comment: Why the `SET ARG=%1`, `IF DEFINED ARG` rather than `IF NOT '%1'==''`?

Comment: @Sinjai: personal preference. :-) I always like to name variables so the intent is clear, and similarly "if defined" communicates the intent better than a comparison.

Comment: @Nate: I figured, just making sure I didn't miss something. It's probably not a bad rule of thumb anyway, as often I find myself consistently interested in, say, `%~1` and named variables allow for substrings, etc. Though these are all concepts I was not familiar with when I made that comment!